# "Failure Is Funny" as a family motto

Tags: translation-check

I'm writing a novella.  In it, I want a motto for a noble family with a strong sense of humour. The family encourages risk taking, learning from failure, and using that failure to build good stories.

I want the family motto to reflect this strongly held idea that taking risks is worthwhile, if not always immediately financially rewarding. It's perfectly fine for the motto to be itself jocular.

So far, I have

```
Defectum est Ridiculam
```

or

```
Falla est Iocosus
```

I do not have a high degree of confidence in either, although I understand "falla" covers both "failure" and "flaw" which seems to be close to what I'm trying to laugh at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got those. They're basically word salad.

I'd suggest *deficere iocosum est* 'to fail is funny'.